# Confusion about migration files on Official Django document

Tags: django, django-migrations

On [Migration Files part of Django Official Document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/#migration-files), it reads:

> **Paragraph 1:** The operations are the key; they are a set of declarative instructions which tell Django what schema changes need to be made. Django scans them and builds an in-memory representation of all of the schema changes to all apps, and uses this to generate the SQL which makes the schema changes.
>
> **Paragraph 2:** That in-memory structure is also **used to work out what the differences are between your models and the current state of your migrations**; Django runs through all the changes, in order, on an in-memory set of models to come up with the state of your models last time you ran makemigrations. It then uses these models to compare against the ones in your models.py files to work out what you have changed

**Q1:** In `differences are between your models and the current state of your migrations`, what exactly `your models` and `current states of your migrations` refer to?  which one refers to the Database Version before this new migration file is applied and which one refers to the Database Version after new migration file is applied?

**Q2:** `That in-memory structure is also used to work out what the differences are between your models and the current state of your migrations`
Isn't this already accomplished by `Django scans them and builds an in-memory representation of all of the schema changes to all apps, and uses this to generate the SQL which makes the schema changes` in Paragraph 1? If so, why it says `is also used to` which makes audience think it is something different from paragraph 1?

**Q3:** As a best practice, should we delete all migrations files every time after successful migration? I just fixed some errors poping up when `makemigrations`, which has bothered me for days, by deleting all existing migration files and `makemigrations` again.

Comment: RE Q3: you should __never__ delete your migration files unless you know what you are doing, they are used to track the current state of your database schema and are used to determine what operations are required to sync the DB with your models

Comment: Q1: Django runs through all your existing migrations to build a picture of what your models and DB look like when the last migration was made, this is the `"current states of your migrations"` this is then compared to the models in your current code `"your models"` and the difference is used to create the next migration

Comment: Q2: Paragraph 1 is talking about how Django parses all your migration files and works out what DB schema altering commands need to be run when you run `manage.py migrate`, paragraph 2 is talking about how new migration files are created by determining the difference between your models and your current migration files

Comment: Your explanation is much easier to understand. Django should use your explaining to replace those paragraphs in official document. :)  Since we should never delete existing migration files, in What cases and why deleting existing migration files actually fixs the migration errors ?

Comment: If you create a migration file but get an error when trying to apply it to your DB, sometimes it's best to delete the migration and recreate it after fixing your models. This only applies if the migration __hasn't__ been applied successfully to the DB, deleting a migration that has already been applied is asking for trouble as Django will think your DB is in a state that it is not. Once you get comfortable with migrations you may start editing them manually or deleting them but I would hold off on doing that until you know what you are doing